# jQuery Ajax and Soccer Live Score API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

Can some one please let me know if there is a Live Score API like Google Finance API available to use by jQuery and Ajax?

I google this for more that 3 hours and the only thing which I found was a WordPress plugin. Can you please let me know if this is doable using jQuery and Ajax? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UEFA or FIFA don't seem to provide direct API to get the information

use [optasports](http://www.optasports.com/) or [espn](http://developer.espn.com/docs/scores#using-the-api)

Ex:For http://developer.espn.com

1)request your developer key (Register)

2)Confirm your email address

3)http://developer.espn.com/io-docs put API Key:

then you will get as json or XML format data

```
http://api.espn.com/:version/:resource/:method?apikey=:yourkey
```

then

```
http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/events
```

Comment: Hi RahulG, Thanks for reply but can you please let me know how I can get access to scores XML or json data on these sources?

Comment: Looks like ESPN is discontinuing their public API as of Dec 8, 2014. http://developer.espn.com/blog/read/publicretirement

Answer (score 0):

ESPN already discontinue their public APIs..
check this 
http://espn.go.com/static/apis/devcenter/blog/read/publicretirement.html

Answer (score 0):

Hooks Data provides a real-time API for major US sports including NFL, MBL, NBA, Soccer, NHL.

1) Get API KEY here: https://www.hooksdata.io/signup?invite=SM4555

2) Subscribe to soccer results:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
"query": "SELECT * FROM SoccerGames WHERE away_team.team_name = 'Real Madrid' OR home_team.team_name = 'Real Madrid' AND start_datetime.countdown = 3600"}' 'http://api.hooksdata.io/v1/subscriptions'
```

3) Optional: Add a Webhooks URL where you want to get the data: https://www.hooksdata.io/webhooks

4) Pull the data using fetch endpoint https://www.hooksdata.io/docs/api/api-reference/#query-datasource

5) Get all the data in JSON:

```
{
"matches_count": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "_entity_type": "SoccerGame",
        "_id": "SoccerGame_490555",
        "away_score": null,
        "away_team": {
            "_entity_type": "SoccerTeam",
            "_id": "SoccerTeam_86",
            "espn_id": 86,
            "id": "SoccerTeam_86",
            "logo_url": "http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/soccer/500/86.png&h=500",
            "team_name": "Real Madrid"
        },
        "competition": "Spanish Primera División",
        "game_id": "490555",
        "home_score": null,
        "home_team": {
            "_entity_type": "SoccerTeam",
            "_id": null,
            "team_name": "Leganes"
        },
        "link": "http://m.espn.go.com/soccer/gamecast?gameId=490555&lang=EN&wjb=",
        "start_datetime": {
            "countdown": 86970,
            "datetime": "2018-02-21T17:45:00+0000",
            "timestamp": 1519235100
        },
        "status": "FUTURE",
        "timestamp": 1519235100
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to have videos (goals, highlights) on your website - ScoreBat provides a free API for that - https://www.scorebat.com/video-api/